# Not able to enter a string in the TextField of UI-(iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, applet

I brought a new MAC-MINI before this i was using MAC BOOk Pro..

i am facing some problem with xcode, the problem  is when i run the Application where ever  there is a TextField in the UI when i click to enter its not taking input,it takes hardly 1 or 2 strings and throws thread....

when i try to enter its throwing Thread in main() function telling EXC_BAD_ACCESS...

NOTE:The apps which were working before in Mac book Pro's xcode i mean apps which contains TEXTFIELD in the UI is also not taking input in the present xcode of MAC MINI.

if i tried without writing any code just placing a TextField in the UI and running it ,even then i am not able to enter anything in the UI its just throw Thread in main() function EXC_BAD_ACCESS..

I am not able to solve this issue may i know why its happening like this?

ITS NOT TAKING  ANY INPUT IN TEXTFIELD OF PREVIOUS WORKING APPS AS WELL..

Is the problem with Xcode?

Plz Suggest me to solve this issue..

Thank u

Comment: The problem is probably not with XCode, but we can only tell if you post some code for us to look at, and tell us how you built de app, using Interface Designer or just with Code?

Comment: Would also help if you posted the stack trace from the crash, cheers..

Comment: @ophychius i tried with writing code  and placing a Textfield in UI,after running when i run it its throwing thread this is one issue...
one more issue is even i tried without writing any code just placing a TextField in UI and running,atleast it should take input in  TextField there also i am facing same issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting an object as the textField's delegate?

When you type in the text field, it tries to call its delegate (if it's not nil) to notify about a change in the text. If for whatever reason the delegate is dealloc'ed, you get this type of error, as the textField is trying to reference a deallocated object.

Comment: i am not seeting any object to textField delegate i faced this problem in one of the apps so i  tried with just creating a project of view based application,opened nib file and placed a textfield in UI, and tried Running it...i tried writing code and also without writing any code...

Comment: Yes that might be the issue as well,as you start typing in the textfield it calls its delegate method..

Comment: @Sabby No actually none of my APPS are working which contains TEXTFIELD in the UI part,Which were working FYN before, now i shifted to MAc-MINI..

Comment: Well without seeing the code i would not be able to tell you more..Could you do one thing..Do it programetically  and see if the problem is still there..What i can judge now is the problem with your nib file,though i am not sure but you should give a hit...

Comment: @Sabby yup i got it...i went to settings,then in keyboard i changed the Auto capitalization to OFF mode...

Comment: Use the Profile option to open Instruments, enable NSZombieDetection and try to see what is the dangling pointer that you have that is causing the BAD_ACCESS crash (how to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215176/xcode-instruments-enable-nszombie-detection-where-is-it)

Comment: Fine...Finally you got that....so you changed the setting in the nib....cheers....If it helped you can even vote my comment...